# Why does Maven Surefire 3 fail to run my Cucumber test in Jenkins with Docker?

Tags: java, maven, docker, jenkins, cucumber-jvm

I have a Java project with some Cucumber tests and some regular JUnit tests, managed by Maven.

I want to run the tests in Jenkins, using Docker, so I wrote this `Jenkinsfile`:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'maven:3.6.1'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn clean verify -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true'
            }
            post {
                success {
                    junit 'target/surefire-reports/**/*.xml'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the build, the regular tests pass but the Cucumber tests fail with:

> **Error Message**
>
> URI has a query component
>
> **Stacktrace**
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has a query component

It's not until I disable `trimStackTrace` for `maven-surefire-plugin` that I also get the details:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has a query component
    at java.base/java.io.File.<init>(File.java:427)
    at cucumber.runtime.io.ZipResourceIterator.<init>(ZipResourceIterator.java:22)
    at cucumber.runtime.io.ZipResourceIteratorFactory.createIterator(ZipResourceIteratorFactory.java:24)
    at cucumber.runtime.io.ZipThenFileResourceIteratorFactory.createIterator(ZipThenFileResourceIteratorFactory.java:22)
    at cucumber.runtime.io.DelegatingResourceIteratorFactory.createIterator(DelegatingResourceIteratorFactory.java:49)
    at cucumber.runtime.io.ClasspathResourceIterable.iterator(ClasspathResourceIterable.java:35)
    at cucumber.runtime.io.ResourceLoaderClassFinder.getDescendants(ResourceLoaderClassFinder.java:25)
    at cucumber.runtime.Reflections.instantiateSubclasses(Reflections.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.BackendModuleBackendSupplier.loadBackends(BackendModuleBackendSupplier.java:52)
    at cucumber.runtime.BackendModuleBackendSupplier.get(BackendModuleBackendSupplier.java:39)
    at cucumber.runner.ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.createRunner(ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.java:42)
    at cucumber.runner.ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.access$000(ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.java:13)
    at cucumber.runner.ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier$1.initialValue(ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.java:22)
    at cucumber.runner.ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier$1.initialValue(ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.java:19)
    at java.base/java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:172)
    at cucumber.runner.ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.get(ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.java:38)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber$RunCucumber.evaluate(Cucumber.java:146)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)
```

This is quite puzzling because:

- when running `mvn verify` locally, it works
- when using `agent any` in the `Dockerfile`, instead of the maven Docker image, it works
- when using `maven-surefire-plugin` version `2.22.2` instead of `3.0.0-M3`, it works

I logged in as Jenkins and looked in the workspace:

```
$ sudo su - jenkins

$ ls /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/question-mark-dir_master
'?'   Jenkinsfile   LICENSE   pom.xml   README.md   src   target
```

There's a question mark (`?`) directory in there, and it contains the `.m2` directory, with all the artifacts needed by the project.
I suspect this could be the cause of the exception, because then there are question marks in the classpath, and question marks are the ones who introduce the query component of URIs.

For the moment I can downgrade to `maven-surefire-plugin` version `2.22.2` as a workaround.
But what is the actual problem here?

- Could it be a bug in the new `maven-surefire-plugin`? Judging by the stack trace I wouldn't bet on that.
- Is it a problem in Jenkins or in the Maven docker image (which one?), that causes a directory to have such an unfortunate name?
- Am I doing something wrong?

If you want to try this out, I have [a MVCE](https://gitlab.com/dev-samples/question-mark-dir).
In my local Jenkins installation, I created a new project of type "Multibranch Pipeline" and in "Branch Sources" I added as the git project repository my local git project. No other changes.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Try setting your user.home java system property [export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Duser.home=/home/user]

Comment: I just tried replacing the step in the `Jenkinsfile` with `sh 'MAVEN_OPTS="-Duser.home=/var/lib/jenkins" mvn clean verify ...'`. I got an error saying "Could not create local repository at /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository".

Comment: Definitely a maven problem. You have to sort out why maven creates a question mark directory. Easiest would be to launch maven in debug mode and attach a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By combining TYY's [comment to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/98692029?noredirect=1) and the [documentation of the maven docker image](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/maven/#how-to-use-this-image), I was able to configure the `Jenkinsfile` in a way that avoids creating a question mark directory.

We need to inform Maven of the user's home directory, and map that to a directory outside the container.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'maven:3.6.1'
            args '-v /var/lib/jenkins:/usr/src/mymaven -w /usr/src/mymaven'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'MAVEN_OPTS="-Duser.home=/usr/src/mymaven" mvn clean verify -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true'
            }
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

- `-v /var/lib/jenkins:/usr/src/mymaven` maps the `/var/lib/jenkins` directory on the host to the `/usr/src/mymaven` directory inside the container
- `-w /usr/src/mymaven` sets the working directory inside the container
- `MAVEN_OPTS="-Duser.home=/usr/src/mymaven"` sets the `user.home` Java property for Maven

Proof that it works, on [a branch](https://gitlab.com/dev-samples/question-mark-dir/commits/feature/user_home) of the MCVE.